What is the explanation for nested svg behavior?


<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="outline: 1px solid red">
  <svg  width="50px" height="80px" 
    style="outline: 1px solid green"
  >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="10" style="stroke: black; fill: none;"/>
  </svg>
</svg>



If you see in Chrome browser the outline for inner SVG only encapsulates the circle which is being drawn, you can also try to change the radius of the circle.
I was expecting svg outline to show the box of width 50px by 80px as defined by the width and height attribute.
Am I missing something in nested SVG behavior?

In general do not set width on your SVG in the SVG code. Rely on the viewbox to size things and the size the SVG with CSS.

While this may be a chromium (and from my tests also a webkit) bug not respecting the specs I recommend to avoid nested SVGs and opt for transformed groups. Nested SVGs introduce a lot of cross-browser issues. Frankly, I wonder why FF renders a box according to the nested SVG width/height attributes. A  CSS outline property should from my understanding relate to a content's bounding box (as retrieved via getBBox() - so the boundaries as defined by all geometry child elements (the <circle>) . @Robert Longson: I'd really appreciate it if you could help to clarify this;)

@herrstrietzel seems like a Chrome bug to me.
